# Send json rpc request in Long connection

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

How can i send rpc request in long connection. Since the default rpc request using the short connection. When i send **many** requests together, the `geth` will break down with `to many open file` error, which means the number of connection exceed the limit.

So is there any way i can send request in long connection?

Comment: Do you want to find a way to retry failed connections? Or do you want to have the connections spaced out?

Comment: For this kind of improvement question, an issue on github is more likely to get something done

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to figure this problem out temporarily.

We can increase the Limit of open file name by modifying the sys configuration file. But i hope the ethereum can add the long connection socket rpc method

Comment: How did you solve this exactly? How did you increase the limit?

Comment: I modify the linux system configure file to increase the maximum open file number.